# Where is the dotnet CLI's default template directory on mac?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, mono

When running template installing command like `dotnet new --install MonoGame.Templates.CSharp`, in which directory does this template files actually reside by default? I am on macOS 10.15 and it is hard to find any info online. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/b1223209644d900702287faea8e9b71f95ec49f8/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-new/NewCommandShim.cs#L87 But surely there is no documentation around that.

Comment: @LexLi it looks promising. will take a look. thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer:
`/System/Volumes/Data/Users/[your_mac_username]/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v3.1.101/packages/`

In addition, I also found VS 2019 for Mac's template location too:
`/System/Volumes/Data/Users/[your_mac_username]/.templateengine/Visual Studio/8.0/packages`

I found it by searching the entire drive, hopefully it could save someone's precious time in the future.

Comment: You can mark it which will help more people with same problem.

Comment: So I found the location `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/[your_mac_username]/.templateengine/Visual Studio/8.0/packages` but it's full of `.nupkg` files. Guess I have to figure out how to "open" these? EDIT: ROFL! I didn't know they were compressed files. Learning something new every day!

Comment: Yup, totally agree that we always have a lot of things to learn ;) For anyone who might be curious, `.nupkg` files are `zip` files, AFAIK. I never had a chance to extract them though.