# Where does "dotnet new templatename" command stores the template?

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli, dotnet-new

I am following tutorial for [Create an Item Template for dotnet new CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template#:%7E:text=dotnet%20new%20stringext-,You%20get%20the%20following%20output,-.)

After running dotnet new stringext I get the message

> The template "Example templates: string extensions" was created successfully.

I look up for the extension in my test folder but I do not see anything new created.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question with an answer for macOS - [Where is the dotnet CLI's default template directory on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441233/where-is-the-dotnet-clis-default-template-directory-on-mac)

On Windows it is also in a `.templateengine` directory inside your user directory - `%HOME%\.templateengine`

Comment: %HOME% should be changed to either %HOMEPATH% or %USERPROFILE%.